# SSIS OLE DB Command Parameter Naming

Tags: ssis

When creating a parameterized oledb command with 2 parameters of type integer. How do I determine what param_o and param_1 maps to. Will param_0 always be mapped to the first question mark and param_1 to the second question mark.

For example. in the below update statement would param_0 map to actionid and param_1 map to documentid?

```
UPDATE Document_Action
SET IntegrationStatus = 'completed'
WHERE ActionId = ?
AND DocumentId =?
```

Comment: yes. That's how it works.

Answer (score 0):

All the question marks are defined in a 0-based array so Param_0 will be the first used question mark.